# Calculation and labeling of partial distances in tracks

Tags: qgis

Google Translate:
I have a school route shape (continuous polylines). How to calculate (and label on the map) in the QGIS the partial distances of stretches between locations, intersections of other roads, bridges, and other points of interest?

Original title and body:

Calculo e rotulação de distancias parciais em trilhas

Tenho um shape de rotas escolares (polilinhas contínuas). Como calcular (e rotular no mapa) no QGIS as distâncias parciais dos trechos entre localidades, intersecções de outras estradas, pontes, e outros pontos de interesse?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to add a length attribute to your geometry layer. This can be done as follows:

- Right click on layer in "Layers" pane and "Open Attribute Table"
- Toggle editing mode
- Add a new field called "Length", decimal number (real) format with a length of 15 or so
- Open up the field calculator
- Select "Update Existing Field"
- Underneath the "Update Existing Field" drop down menu select the newly created "Length" field
- Make sure the field calculator is on the "Expression" tab and type in `$length`
- The "output preview" should show a numerical value for length
- Click OK

The new length field you added should contain length values for each segment. Now you need to assign it as a label. After closing the attribute table:

- right click on the polyline layer in "Layers" pane
- select "Single Labels"
- in "Label with" select your "Length" field
- press Apply/OK

Now the Map canvas should show the segments with a length value. If you would like to play around with the format, reopen the properties window> Labels and experiment with the different settings.